# Is std::shared_ptr assignment atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, smart-pointers

In the context of C++ shared pointers, imagine two threads, t1 and t2, both engaged in assigning values to a shared pointer (s1). If t1 assigns the value 2, and in close succession, t2 endeavors to assign the value 1, will t2 wait for the entirety of t1's assignment, encompassing the memory allocation phase, or will it proceed without waiting?

```
std::shared_ptr<int> s1;

std::thread t1([=s1]() { while (true) s1 = std::make_shared<int>(2); });
std::thread t2([=s1]() { while (true) s1 = std::make_shared<int>(1); });
// ...
```

Comment: Take a look at the [last paragraph](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) of the intro. You can have a data race, because you are accessing copy-assignment operator of `s1` without synchronization.

Comment: No it is not atomic, that is what `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` would be for.

Comment: Also this question has been answered a lot of time already, though usually it is phrased as "is std::shared_ptr threadsafe". So if you want to read more, look for that.

Comment: There is no memory allocation phase in the assignment. There is a deallocation though, if `s1` is the sole owner of the integer.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Can you propose a dupe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` not atomic itself. You can use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` which is partial specialisation for `std::atomic`.